# What is the purpose of R3 in this LED driver circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt

When the input voltage is +3 V, the current in R3 is only 0.24 mA, while the current in R4 is 18 mA. It seems that R3 doesn't play any significant role when the input voltage is +3 V. So why does it exist in the circuit at all?

Some guess: When input voltage is 0 V, R3 guarantees that the base-emitter voltage of Q3 remains 0, and Q3 is not turned on accidentally by electrostatic charges accumulated on base of Q3 or by electromagnetic interference.

[image]

The image is from *The Art of Electronics*, 3rd Ed.

Comment: Please, when you post an image from a copyrighted source, you should cite the source. That is figure 2.16B from Art of Electronics, 3rd edition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *What is the purpose of R3 in this LED driver circuit?*

R3 ensures that any leakage currents passing through Q2 (when it is supposedly off) do not trickle into the base of Q3 and partially turn it on. This might cause the LED to glow dimly.

Leakage might be 100 nA and, through a 10 kΩ resistor would produce an offset of 1 mV to ground and be thoroughly effective against the 100 nA flowing into the base of Q3.

100 kΩ would also be very effective too.

Of course, it may be there for other reasons related to the input signal amplitude (unknown).

The other big reason is operating speed (if modulating the LED with data or generally using PWM). To improve edge rise and fall times you need an emitter resistor on Q2.

The two transistors are in a configuration that is very similar to a Darlington pair and, if you look at the equivalent circuit of some Darlington transistors they also use an emitter resistor on the first transistor to improve switching speed.

Comment: I wouldn't call the combination a Darlington pair, since the two collectors are not connected to the same node.

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine yes, I was a little too weak in that statement. I shall amend.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you took that image from the book "The Art of Electronics", 3rd edition (figure 2.16B). When taking images from books, as for other copyrighted sources, you should cite the source.

Anyway, Andy Aka has already given you a good answer. I'd like to add another perspective.

You can view Q2-R3 as an emitter follower stage whose purpose is to limit the load on the control input source. If you refer to the book where the image come from, the LED load is quite heavy (500mA), so the switch transistor Q3 would need a substantial base current to turn on (some milliamperes with the beta shown in the figure). This means that the source of the control input could have some difficulties in activating the switch.

By interposing an emitter follower, which is responsible for sourcing the current to activate the switch, you relieve the control source from sourcing that current. In other words, the high input impedance of the emitter follower shields the control source from the loading effect of the switch.

Moreover, without the emitter follower, the switch transistor Q3 would need to have a higher beta (to avoid an excessive input current), which is more difficult to achieve in power transistors.